# getting data from an api, but can't render the response

Tags: angularjs

i can get the input and fetch the json i can also insert the data to the
$scope.movies

but i can't see the results.
 what am i missing?

thanks.

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Learning AngularJS</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="mainController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='content' ng-app='MyTutorialApp' ng-controller='MainController'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='searchMovies' />
    <button ng-click='addNew()'>Add</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in movies">1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the app:

```
var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',[])
```

the controller:

```
  app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
  $scope.movies = null;
  $scope.searchMovies = null;
  $scope.addNew = function() {
    if ($scope.searchMovies != null && $scope.searchMovies != "") {
        fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + $scope.searchMovies)
                .then(data => data.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                    $scope.movies = data.Search
                console.log($scope.movies)});
    }
  }
});
```

edit: i'm using live-server to to run this code. maybe it's connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
$scope.movies = data.Search
$scope.$applyAsync()
```

Because you are using `fetch` and not `$http`, Angular does not notice that the scope object has been changed. `$applyAsync` manually schedules the change detection.

To avoid these hassles, I would recommend you to switch to `$http`.

---

Edit: $applyAsync is not available in Angular 1.0.7 - it works if you upgrade to a recent version like `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js`.

Comment: Instead of using `$scope.$applyAsync();` he could wrap the promise in `$q.when()` for similar effect. Some might find that approach cleaner.

Comment: the $applyAsync() did not work. trying now the $http

Comment: Ah, you are using AngularJS 1.0.7 for some reason? That version is really outdated, can you upgrade?

Comment: @user4602966 Beware when using `$http` that the response is passed to the promise a bit differently than with `fetch`. You'll be using the promise like this instead: `.then(response => response.data)`.

Comment: the different version and http fixed the problem :) thank you @stholzm